# Buy one get one free sales with exp:store

Tags: expresso-store

Using Exp:resso's store addon, is it possible to do buy one get one free type sales?

I see the promo codes but they dont seem to have the option to require more than one item in the cart to use it or anything like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this using promo codes and Store. You would be able to create an extension to do this using our custom hooks.

The ability to create discounts like this is high on our [feature request list](https://exp-resso.com/store/support) and will be addressed in a future version (though there is no specific timeframe, so if you need it now it's best to go with an extension).

Answer (score 1):

From recent memory of trying this.  As of the current version this isn't available. Best bet would be a custom extension.